# Can I legally cast a pointer to a struct member to a pointer to the struct?

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider a struct like so, for example:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a, b;
};
```

If I have a pointer `ptr` to an `int` that I know points to `b` in a `Foo` struct, is it legal to do this?

```
Foo *foo = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr) - offsetof(Foo, b));
```

If so, is this legal for any struct? If not, is there any legal way to accomplish the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof:

> The macro **offsetof** expands to a constant of type `std::size_t`, the value of which is the offset, in bytes, from the beginning of an object of specified type to its specified member, including padding if any.
>
> If type is not a [standard layout type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout), the behavior is undefined.

This make uses of `offsetof` subject to undefined behavior for classes and structs that are not standard layout type.

For classes and structs that are standard layout type, I don't see any potential problems.

Comment: @T.C., since `ptr` is being cast to `char*` in the expression, I am not seeing how pointer arithmetic will be a problem.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is only defined for pointers into arrays (for this purpose, something that's not an element of an array is treated as being in an array of size 1). I don't see an array of `char`s anywhere in there.

Comment: @T.C., Assuming that `ptr` indeed points to the `b` member of an instance of `Foo`, you should be able to treat that memory as an array of `char`s. if you can't treat the memory used by a `struct` as an array of `char`, how would `memcpy` ever work?

Comment: `memcpy` works because the standard says it works - it explicitly permits the underlying bytes of a trivially copyable to be copied into a `char` or `unsigned char` array. But that doesn't mean that the underlying bytes of an object can be treated as an array of `char`s.